# Сочетания с годами — нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Из [ПАС Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80):

> § 154. В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире.
>
> <...>
>
> 5. В сочетаниях с цифровыми обозначениями, если цифре предшествует часть, содержащая пробел, напр.: операция «Меченые атомы — 2», сценарий фильма «Место встречи изменить нельзя — 2» (ср. фильм «Спрут-5»).

Грамота также в ответах рекомендует *тире* для сочетаний слов с годом (и дефис в случае одного слова), руководствуясь этим правилом, однако в Википедии в большинстве случаев в статьях об определённых мундиалях тире опускают. Например, в этой [статье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83_2022) фигурирует просто *чемпионат мира по футболу 2022. **Как всё-таки правильно?*** Понятно, что Википедию многие не считают авторитетом, но, может, действительно лучше писать по-простому (без тире), тем более, что согласно Лопатину год хоть и нельзя не считать цифровым обозначением, однако в примерах его и близко нет: он ссылается только на вторые версии фильма и операции.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже встречала такие написания:

> Части света 2021
> https://thewallmagazine.ru/chasti-sveta-2020-festival/
>
> Ответы и задания 5 класс школьный этап 2020 олимпиады по истории:
> https://100balnik.ru.com/%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B

Думаю, это название - просто обозначение, символ, указывающий на именно этот фестиваль, здесь ведь даже кавычек нет, поэтому это не название фестиваля, а цифровой указатель, дата. В поисковике мы ведь тоже иногда пишем только текст без знаков препинания, он распознаёт только текст - символ, указатель.

По Вашей ссылке то же самое: сначала указатель:
Чемпионат мира по футболу 2022‎, англ. 2022 FIFA World Cup), а потом расшифровка:

> — 22-й чемпионат мира по футболу ФИФА, финальная часть которого должна
> пройти в ноябре и декабре 2022 года

В самом тексте написания верны:

> [1]. Несмотря на громкий коррупционный скандал, связанный с выбором
> страны-хозяйки ЧМ-2022[2],

А вот при создании текста мы должны писать по правилам. Вот, например, Грамота отвечает:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B0-20

> - С прописной или строчной буквы пишется слово олимпийский в следующих сочетаниях... Сочи 2014 - с дефисом или без? .
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
>
> Неизменяемое приложение, передаваемое на письме цифрами,
> присоединяется дефисом: Сочи-2014, Олимпиада-2014. Однако в том
> случае, когда перед цифрами стоит не слово, а сочетание слов, дефис
> заменяется на тире: Олимпийские игры – 2014.

Наверное, нам нужно при встрече с такими написаниями спросить себя: это текст или указатель на текст?

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! Товарищ просто советовался, как оформить картинку и текст на ней. Решил он в итоге сделать с тире: "Зимнее путешествие *Кусочки* на Байкал — 2021".

Comment: Я думаю, правильно сделал: по правилам писать всё-таки лучше, не ошибёшься. Картинка - это не справочник онлайн, где нужны указатели.

Comment: Очень рад, Людмила! Сейчас скажу ему. ;)